# Remove extra space between in figure and table lists

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists

There are some spaces between the figure and table lists in my document. How Can I to remove theses spaces? The others lists I don't have problem. Why? Thanks!

```
%tabelas de conteúdo

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} %para prevenir as listas no sumário
\listafiguras
\listatabelas
\listaquadros
\listagraficos 
%\listaalgoritmos
\listadesiglas
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}} %para começar a colocar itens no sumário
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %número de hierarquia de seções
\sumario  % \tableofcontents
```

[image]

Comment: I know that \documentclass{book} adds extra space between chapters, but fixing it would require replacing the \@chapter macro.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Or patching it... as long as there is no additional information by the O.P. it's only guessing. I wonder about the Portuguese (?) names of the macros. This is most likely no standard class!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Either way you copy and edit the original macro.  The only question is whether you want to see the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

The standard classes, and I have no idea which class you are using, insert a 10pt space in the lists of figure and table headings that are in different chapters. If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article` classes) then the command 
`\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}`
will eliminate those spaces.